# Reading a Message from Kafka and writing to HDFS

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-kafka

I'm looking for the best way to read messages (alot of messages, around 100B each day) from Kafka, after reading the message I need to make manipulate on data and write it into HDFS.

- If I need to do it with the best performance, What is the best way for me to read messages from Kafka and write file into HDFS?
- Which programming language is best for that?
- Do I need to consider to use solutions like Spark for that?

Answer (score 1):

You should use Spark streaming for this (see [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/streaming-kafka-0-10-integration.html)), it provides simple correspondence between Kafka partitions and Spark partitions.

Or you can use Use Kafka Streams (see [more](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/)). Kafka Streams is a client library for building applications and microservices, where the input and output data are stored in Kafka clusters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Spark, Flink, NiFi, Streamsets... but Confluent provides [Kafka Connect HDFS](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/connect-hdfs/docs/index.html) exactly for this purpose.

The Kafka Connect API is somewhat limited in transformations, so what most people do is to write a Kafka Streams job to filter/enhance the data to a secondary topic, which then is written to HDFS

Note: These options will write many files to HDFS (generally, one per Kafka topic partition)

> Which programming language is best for that?

Each of the above are using Java. But you don't need to write any code yourself if using NiFi, Streamsets, or Kafka Connect

Comment: There is also [KSQL](http://confluent.io/ksql) to consider for doing transformations